# Can SpEL use a special date format for a bean property?

Tags: date, javabeans, date-format, spring-3, spring-el

I have a bean with a date property called birthday:

`<property name="birthday" value="06/12/1980"/>`

Can I specify a date format for my bean, in order to get 6th December or 12th June or is the default one always used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are options:

- Inject the date and format in your bean to return the desired string representation.
- Use the `Formatter` SPI and configure an instance of `DateFormatter` given to you out of the box. Here is the [Javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/datetime/DateFormatter.html).
- Implement and register your own instance of `Formatter` and then pass it to `@Formatted` annotation. Or use other annotations for more special cases. This is described [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/previews/ui-format.html).